# NameResolvingRequestBuilder$RotateIpListFactory error when calling external rest URL from a mule flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft

I have written below mule flow which calls another external rest URL "http://localhost:7070/rest/products" through-flow reference. The external URL returns a list of products and its server is up and running.

But when I call the URL through a mule flow, I am receiving below exception:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mulesoft.service.http.impl.service.client.builder.NameResolvingRequestBuilder$RotateIpListFactory. 
I have provided a full error log at the end. Please help.

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="0b9778e7-201b-4cbf-9c2b-551f47044bd4" basePath="/rest" >
    <http:request-connection host="localhost" port="7070" />
</http:request-config>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="c29e17c2-66e2-4685-bdd6-ee80245f63a8" >
    <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
</http:listener-config>
<flow name="mainflow" doc:id="4b8f4f18-f462-4bc3-bc20-ddee90d86dbd" >
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="5458e296-cc0d-4d58-921a-c35483cfb838" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/products"/>
    <flow-ref doc:name="Flow Reference" doc:id="4e2a1241-5ffe-4167-adec-a7e2412d0a59" name="config-resr-callFlow"/>
</flow>
<flow name="config-resr-callFlow" doc:id="e004e7f3-f231-4c55-b95c-72dd6fd2c05e" >
    <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" doc:id="78e7368c-316a-4cbc-9f34-3cb9de0f4dcc" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/products"/>
</flow>
```

Error log:

```
ERROR 2019-09-23 06:54:34,399 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.16: [rest-consumer].config-resr-callFlow.CPU_LITE @e96cb7f] [event: cfedad70-ddb5-11e9-b57d-3c9180706ae0] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnCriticalErrorHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : com/mulesoft/service/http/impl/service/client/builder/NameResolvingRequestBuilder$RotateIpListFactory.
Element               : config-resr-callFlow/processors/0 @ rest-consumer:config-resr-call.xml:18 (Request)
Element XML           : <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" doc:id="78e7368c-316a-4cbc-9f34-3cb9de0f4dcc" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/products"></http:request>
Error type            : MULE:CRITICAL
Payload Type          : org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mulesoft.service.http.impl.service.client.builder.NameResolvingRequestBuilder$RotateIpListFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.classloader.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findLocalClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:171)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.classloader.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.mulesoft.service.http.impl.service.client.builder.NameResolvingRequestBuilder.nextResolvedAddresses(NameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:99)
    at com.mulesoft.service.http.impl.service.client.builder.NameResolvingRequestBuilder.setUri(NameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:78)
    at com.mulesoft.service.http.impl.service.client.builder.NameResolvingRequestBuilder.setUri(NameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:32)
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.client.GrizzlyHttpClient.createGrizzlyRequest(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:418)
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.client.GrizzlyHttpClient.sendAsync(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:352)
    at com.mulesoft.service.http.impl.service.client.EEGrizzlyHttpClient.sendAsync(EEGrizzlyHttpClient.java:140)
    at org.mule.runtime.http.api.client.HttpClient.sendAsync(HttpClient.java:106)
    at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.HttpRequesterConnectionManager$ShareableHttpClient.sendAsync(HttpRequesterConnectionManager.java:104)
    at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.client.HttpExtensionClient.send(HttpExtensionClient.java:72)
    at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.HttpRequester.doRequestWithRetry(HttpRequester.java:124)
    at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.HttpRequester.doRequest(HttpRequester.java:103)
    at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.HttpRequestOperations.request(HttpRequestOperations.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.java:80)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodComponentExecutor.java:79)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ReflectiveMethodOperationExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodOperationExecutor.java:64)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.ReactiveOperationExecutionWrapper.lambda$execute$0(ReactiveOperationExecutionWrapper.java:65)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3694)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:3800)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3688)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3655)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3627)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$executeWithInterceptors$9(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:159)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3694)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:389)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmit(FluxFlatMap.java:501)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:943)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2070)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:933)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3694)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:389)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:292)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:285)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:292)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:285)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:484)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: More information is needed: Which is the version of the Mule Runtime?
Is it the enterprise edition or the community edition? Version of the HTTP connector?

Comment: Mule runtime version is 4.2.1. It is a community edition, Anypoint studio version is 7.3.4. HTTP version is 1.5.3

Comment: I'm not sure that 4.2.1 is considered a community edition. There seems to be problem related to that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seem to be that there is a mixing of Enterprise and Community features. The stack trace shows Mule invoking the EEGrizzlyHttpClient class which is available in the Enterprise edition. The community edition would have the GrizzlyHttpClient class instead. Maybe some services are mixed in the installation. If you look into the directory MULE_HOME/services and see a directory `mule-service-http-ee-1.4.3` then it is an enterprise installation of the HTTP service (note the 'ee' part). The error indicates Mule is trying to use but is the community edition instead. I recommend to install a fresh distribution of Mule to be sure it is clean.

Also it is recommended to use the latest version of the HTTP connector in your applications. See the latest at the top of the [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/connector-http) page and update the version in the pom.xml file of the project.